# ¿Por qué me da error? Es en python

Tags: python, while

```
bandera = True
while bandera:
    if deseo = Si
    deseo = str(input("Desea continuar: Si/No "))
    else:
        deseo = ("No")
        bandera = False
```

Comment: Te faltó agregar el error

Comment: La indentación está mal en el if.

Comment: Tienes error en `if deseo = Si` -> `if deseo = "Si":`. Además la línea de debajo 
`deseo = str(...)` debería estar indentada un nivel más.

Answer (score 1):

que tal primero que nada te recomiendo que vayas y leas
[Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

El estaba en la condición del if, además de que el else no lleva condición.
Yo lo haría de la siguiente manera.

```
bandera = True

while bandera: 
    deseo = str(input("Desea continuar: Si/No ")) 
    if deseo != "Si":  
        bandera = False
```

Saludos

Comment: No veo necesidad alguna de declarar ```deseo``` más arriba ya que el valor que reciba lo obtendrá del input

Comment: Buen punto no hace falta, Saludos...

Answer (score 0):

Una solución más simple. No requiere ninguna variable; el simple hecho de que termino el `while` señala que el usuario dejo de ingresar `Si` e ingreso un `No`.

```
while input("Desea continuar: Si/No ") == 'Si':
    pass
```